# Es posible ordenar los queryset en el ADMIN según su relación Foreign Key en Django?

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo en Django y estoy tratando de crear una app que pueda mostrar los modelos País, Ciudad y Persona, relacionados con su Foreign Key. Mi idea es crear una Persona (desde el admin) y que esta se relacione con un País y una Ciudad, pero que estos últimos estén filtrados. Es decir: Al seleccionar País (Ej: Chile) muestre solamente las ciudades relacionadas con ese país. He buscado varias formas por Internet, desde django-autoselect-light con select2 hasta cambiar los Foreign Key por GenericForeignKey pero nada ha resultado. Alguien quizás que me ayude a ver la luz?